# Android 11+ Unable to gather ice candidates in webview or chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, webrtc, google-chrome-devtools

I have an Android app that loads a Webview and the webview plays a WebRTC video. However, I noticed that both the android system webview and the normal chrome browser are both unable to gather ice candidates on android 11+ (SDK 30+).

To reproduce:
Go to URL: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/
and click the "Gather Candidates" button.

On Firefox: You can see a list of candidates
[image]

On Chrome: It is unable to find any.
[image]

I know that used to work in the past on chrome.

Does anyone know if there is some setting I have to enable now to gather ice candidates in chrome? Is this a bug?

I have noticed this same behavior in Android webview targeting SDK 30 or above. Compiling an app with a webview that targets SDK 29 works, but targeting SKD 30 fails to gather ice candidates in the system webview (which is chrome based).

Hoping someone confirm if this is a bug or if perhaps its device / network specific? Anyone run into this issue and have a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with Chrome on some Samsung devices with Android 11 and higher. See https://crbug.com/1240237 for more information.

Source: I wrote https://crrev.com/4cf629764739560cc12068e32fc6526b17b7615d

Comment: I was still seeing this error on devices some devices. The workaround that solved this for me was adding `iceCandidatePoolSize: 1` to the RTCPeerConnection call. e.g.`new RTCPeerConnection({iceCandidatePoolSize : 1})`